# prcomp "Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric"

Tags: r, pca

I'm brand new to R and I'm presently trying to create a PCA plot for a project. I created tables of my data in excel and then saved it as a .csv file, which I declared as a variable as follows:

```
> har.lip <-read.csv("HData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> head(har.lip[, 1:3])
      NAME   NUM1     NUM80
1  IN-3  4.347214  8.247082
2  IN-4  3.666815  8.108210
3  IN-5  5.779208 12.329948
4  IN-7  6.205594 22.449827
5  IN-7  5.342581 10.762976
6  IN-3  4.538335  9.711204
> pca <- prcomp(har.lip)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I've tried adapting other solutions on here to my own and it doesn't seem to be working. I've been following a tutorial, but I could use some additional assistance. Thanks!

Comment: Eventually `prcomp(har.lip[-1])` ? Please put the output of `str(har.lip)` in your question!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data frame it looks like the first column is a string. `prcomp` doesn't tolerate strings. Something you could do would be:

```
har.lip <-read.csv("HData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

# Coerce to matrix, remove the first column which has characters
har.lip_mat <- as.matrix(har.lip[ ,-1])

# run function on the matrix
pca <- prcomp(har.lip_mat)
```

This should give you the desired output.

To illustrate some of your additional questions here is a more extended reprex:

```
library(dplyr)

# Make a data set that looks like yours
sim_data <- mtcars %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "id")

# Make your data set a matrix and remove non-numeric columns
sim_data_mat <- as.matrix(sim_data[ ,-1])

# Add row names to your matrix from original data ste
rownames(sim_data_mat) <- sim_data[ ,1]

# Keep complete cases only

sim_data_mat <- sim_data_mat[complete.cases(sim_data_mat),]

# Now run your 
prcomp(sim_data_mat)
``
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to run this and I ran into this error:

Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Some of my fields do contain values of "0," but everything else is numeric

Comment: It means you have some ``NA``s in your data. You can remove those with ``na.omit(har.lip_mat)`` (granted from a theoretical perspective it is important that they are missing at random)

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for your help. I ran this and it seemed to work, but I'm still getting the same error when I try to use prcomp().

Comment: Ok, so I finally got it to work. It appears that there was a value missing in the table. Sorry for that question. Would it be possible for me to keep the names of each item as a label within the PCA plot?